# Show status (image) PHP MySQL

Tags: php, image, replace, status

I need to show the status of the employee’s presence in the office, the code below works but I would like to display only one image at the time to show if the employee is in the office. At the moment for example if the employee stamps his attendance am_in and then am_out on his status two images are showed.

```
if ($row_io['am_in'] == !NULL || $row_io['pm_in'] == !NULL) {
    echo '<img src="../images/in.png">';
    }
    else ($row_io['am_out'] == !NULL || $row_io['pm_out'] == !NULL) {
        echo '<img src="../images/out.png">';
        }
```

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KMdYdH

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the decision logic from the output, so it's easier to debug:

```
$isEmployeeIn = isEmployeeIn($row_io);
printf('<img src="../images/%s.png>', $isEmployeeIn ? 'in' : 'out');
```

You then put anything needed for the logic into `isEmployeeIn` and the separated output takes care that you only display one image at a time.

By the way:

```
$row_io['am_in'] == !NULL || $row_io['pm_in'] == !NULL
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$row_io['am_in'] || $row_io['pm_in']
```

Try to reduce the code to the minimum so you can't make that many mistakes.

Comment: +1, and have separate files for logic and templates if you can.